# How to have textfield hint and text change work perfectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, textbox

In my HTML page, I have a text field where I display a hint in it, and also assign a text change event to it (that works after the user stops typing for 1 second).

But I can't get them to work properly together.

I want the `RunSearch` function to occur when the text changes in the input field. But it needs to ignore when the text is empty string or the hint string as well. However, when I focus on the field, the text changes from the hint to empty string which triggers the text change event, which does the `else` block from the first function, which I don't want to happen when you focus or blur and the new text is empty or the search hint.

Is there a way when you focus or blur the input field, and the new text is either empty or the search hint because of the focus or blur event, you can stop the text change event from happening?

Thanks.

```
function InitSearchBox(searchBoxID, searchButtonID, scope, searchLimit, treeviewID, searchErrorMessageBoxID, searchHint) {

    // initializes the search button so it does the same thing as stop typing in the search box
    $("#" + searchButtonID).click(function () {
        var text = $("#" + searchBoxID).val();
        alert(text);
        if (text != "" && text != searchHint) {
            RunSearch(text, scope, searchBoxID, searchLimit, treeviewID, searchErrorMessageBoxID);
        } else {
            $("#" + searchErrorMessageBoxID).html("");
            RevealAllNodesOnTreeview(treeviewID);
        }
    });

    // this part will make it so that after 1 second after the user stops typing in the search box, it will run the search request
    var PDFSearchBoxTimeout = null;
    $("#" + searchBoxID).bind("propertychange input", function () {
        if (PDFSearchBoxTimeout !== null) {
            clearTimeout(PDFSearchBoxTimeout);
        }
        PDFSearchBoxTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#" + searchButtonID).click();
        }, 1000);
    });
}


function SetSearchBoxHint(searchHint, searchInputBoxID) {

    // get the search box element
    var my_element = $("#" + searchInputBoxID);

    // this part occurs when you focus/blur on the search box, and will change its text and text colour depending on the scenario
    $(my_element).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == searchHint) {
            $(this).val("").css({ "color": "black" });
        }
    });

    $(my_element).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val(searchHint).css({ "color": "gray" });
        }
    });

    // force the blur to occur on the search box
    $(my_element).blur();
}
```

**Update:**

```
function SetSearchBoxHint(searchHint, searchInputBoxID) {

    // get the search box element
    var my_element = $("#" + searchInputBoxID);

    // this part occurs when you focus/blur on the search box, and will change its text and text colour depending on the scenario
    $(my_element).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == searchHint) {
            $(my_element).prop('disabled', true);
            $(this).val("").css({ "color": "black", "font-style": "normal" });
            $(my_element).prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    $(my_element).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(my_element).prop('disabled', true);
            $(this).val(searchHint).css({ "color": "gray", "font-style": "italic" });
            $(my_element).prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    // force the blur to occur on the search box
    $(my_element).blur();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider using `.keyup()` instead?

Comment: Actually, is there I way I can temporarily disable the input event then enable it after?

Comment: Sure, just set `$('element:input').attr('disabled','disabled')`. But, will that solve your problem?

Comment: Why do you have `attr('disabled','disabled')`? Do I replace the first disabled with something? Also, I think it would fix it, because on the blur/focus events, I can just disable the text change event, then show empty string or search hint, then enable the text change function again.

Comment: It's the way the DOM actually looks for the disabled attribute. `<input type="text" name="something" disabled="true" />`. Sorry, use `$('element:input').prop('disabled',true)` instead.

Comment: I added my new function above, but it didn't work... It acting really weird now.

Comment: You're going to need to create a jsFiddle which shows all your HTML markup to really get some educated input on this.

Comment: Im going to try another thing, try to create my own custom attribute, and set it to yes in the beginning of the blur/focus event, then remove it at the end, then in the text change event, check that attribute.

Comment: Wow.. you have a lot going on there! - by the way - check out my answer to your question about the custom icon in the accordion widget.

Comment: I finally got it working, by setting a global variable, and change it to true, in the beginning of the blur/focus function, then in the end, I changed it to false, to simulate a synchronization lock effect. Then I could just check that variable in the text change event.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("my_element").keyup(function(){
        // your code
    })
})
```

You can use keyup event of textbox so it will not fire when textbox is blank so you can put placeholder as well.

Comment: I changed it from keyup to input, because it needs to support right click + delete/cut/paste/undo.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Answers need to solve a specific problem and should incorporate the OP's code in a more meaningful manner.